# Powershell - get-adgroupmembers - cannot contact server

Tags: powershell, active-directory, connection

I went to use the following
 Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-ADGroupMember -server ourdomain.com -Identity "AU-TEAM Testing" | Select Name, SamAccountName, objectClass 
and get below..

Initially i thought it was because i was using PowerGui, but i tried with the normal win 7 powershell, same error. I tried with no -server, with -server with the domain name and the DC machine name.

NB: Adexplorer, and the AD admin tools worked fine, so it is not as if the AD was not there.

Now the DC is an old 2003 box.

> > Is that the issue ?
> >
> > I did a google and could not find anything too useful. Anyone know of a sequence to test this ?
> >      One article referred to a adws service which is not installed on win 7 client.

Error:
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Unable to contact the server. This may be because this server does not exist, it

is currently down, or it does not have the Active Directory Web Services running.,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory

.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember"

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You've got the answer in the error message.

If you've got a W2K3 Active-Directory, you can't acces it with PowerShell V2.0 Active-Directory module unless you install a special service on you server (Begining W2K3 R2 as far as I remenber).

Have a look to [Active Directory Web Service for Windows Server](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2852).

An alternative is to use the Quest [Free PowerShell Commands for Active Directory](http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the Quest link, post answered

Comment: @user2935199 So you can put it as an answer.